# Publishing Phonegap App to Blackberry AppWorld

Tags: cordova, blackberry

I'm submitting phonegap app to BB AppWorld but confuse what to submit.
Following command is run to build the source

```
ant blackberry build
```

- MyApp.zip [file]
- OTAInstall [folder - 66 cod files and one jad]
- StandardInstall [folder - containing MyApp.alx, cod, csl and cso files]
- widget [folder - source files including index.html]

After that signed the package

```
bbwp MyApp.zip -g passwordhere -o /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyApp/build/signed
```

and I got following file and folders under **signed** folder

- OTAInstall [folder - **66 cod files and one jad**]
- StandardInstall [folder - containing **MyApp.alx, MyApp.cod, MyApp.csl and MyApp.cso** files]

Which file and folder should I choose to submit to AppWorld?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi just you required to make one release.zip according to following link

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/47831/664046.jsp

here you need to take only one **MyApp.cod** file which is available in StandardInstall folder remaining settings you need tofollw as per link